# What is the current relationship status of Tony and Ziva in NCIS?

Tags: ncis

Can anyone say what is the current relationship status of Tony and Ziva? Are they really keeping in contact? Are they dating?

Comment: How far are you into the series?  It really depends on if you've kept up the whole time, or if you are in the middle as to what the answer could be.

Comment: @New-To-IT I would guess from the "Are they keeping in contact" that the OP's at least in the current season.

Comment: I didn't want to assume anything and ruin it for them, and to correctly answer the question, I figured the episode they are on should be in the question.

Comment: I don't think we're supposed to know (yet).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that is currently known, as of season 12. It is assumed based on how Ziva left the show that they're still on good terms and that a future reunion is possible but whether this becomes the focus of something that occurs on screen or not is another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt,

1. They probably had sex on several occasions while on assignment. That's their business.
2. They had sex at least once since Tony is the biological father of their child (S13E24).